# How to Connect VB.Net to a LAN's another PC's Wamp Server

Tags: vb.net, wamp, lan

I'm trying to connect my `VB.net` project to WAMP server of another PC inside the same network. But I'm having a problem. Thanks in advance...

#### My code:

Module modMain

```
Public con As New MySqlConnection("Server=192.168.254.102;port=8081;uid=root;pwd=;database=dbpabzkie")

Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
Public reader As MySqlDataReader
Public Sub ConnectMe()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If

    con.Open()
End Sub
```

this is my code to connect it to wamp...

Comment: You should add your code here and also show error you got.

Comment: MySql only listens to 127.0.0.1 by default. You have to configure the MySql server to listen for your machine to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to MYSQL it normally listens on port 3306. It is likely that Apache may have been changed to listen on 8081 but not MYSQL.

However WAMPServers MYSQL is configured, like most MYSQL installs to only allow connections from the PC running the MYSQL Server, for obvious security reasons!

As it is never a good idea to amend the MYSQL Super User account `root` to allow access from another PC, I suggest you will have to create a new user account on the WAMPServer MYSQL instance, that is allowed to connect from your PC's ip address, or possibly any ip on your local network.
Also make sure that this new user account has all the required privilages on the datebase `dbpabzkie` (and only that database).

See references below for how to do that.

> References:
>
> [How to setup user accounts on MYSQL from the MYSQL Console](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)
>
> [How to setup user accounts using phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html)

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thank you for your comments :) .. I've got my answer now.. simply what I'm trying to do is to allow my server's sql database to be on LAN..

I just..
Grant privileges on mysql console inorder to allow any hosts to be connected and add port 3306 on firewall.. then uses my server's ip address as server when using connection string..

ps. im bad at english